# Accessing value of javascript file input variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the filepath of the selected file. 
Using the debugger, I see that the file has an property called value which is equal to : `"C:\fakepath\filename.txt"`.
However when I try to access file.value, the filepath is equal to null.
I am using Java 8, Struts 1.2, Jsps, and Chrome
Javascript:

```
function validateFile(file)
{
    filepath = file.value; /*This is null*/
    return true; 
}
```

Html:

```
<input type="file" id="theFile[0]" onChange="validateFile(this)"/>
```

Comment: You aren't trying to *set* the value property of anything in that example that I can see. Are you sure that's the right code for the error?

Comment: I agree with the above comment. Try changing onChange to `validateFile(this)` and instead of `function validateFile(fileid)` use `function validateFile(file)`. Remove the variable declaration for `var file` also.

Comment: @Quentin `filepath = file.value` when `var file = ...` was set isn't an attempt to set the value property with `filepath`?

Comment: @8protons, `Cannot set property 'value'` means something basically did `undefined.value = ...` there is no code in the example that does that

Comment: @Quentin you are right. The .value is for another part of the code. My apologies. The value of filepath is just null.

Comment: @8protons — No. It is the exact opposite. It sets `filepath` with `file.value`.

Comment: Ah okay, I was confused. Thanks

Comment: Also what's going on with `allowed`?

Comment: @JonathanGray I am trying to search through allowed to see if the file extension `ext` is found. If it is not found, then the file type should not be uploaded.

Comment: I think this is a security feature of the browser to prevent you from being able to see the directory structure of the client machine.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_accept.asp

Comment: @JonathanGray yes, I would prefer to do it to the way shown above. I am currently trying to get the filepath. However, the filepath is equal to null.

Comment: Try using `this` as I stated in my first comment and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @zzzzBov edited the question to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it wasn't too much work after all :)

```js
function validateFile(file)
{
    filepath = file.value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = filepath;
    return true; 
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onChange="validateFile(this)"/>
<div id="result">[result will be here]</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
function validateFile(fileinput) {
    var allowed = "pdf,png";
    var filepath=fileinput.value;
    var ext = filepath.substr(filepath.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    if (filepath = "" || allowed.search(ext) <= -1) {
        fileinput.value='';
        alert('Invalid file type');
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputFile" onChange="validateFile(this)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I just fixed the problem using Jonathan's answer.

Comment: I have also +1'd this answer as it would have in fact fixed the issue.